# How to set a lifetime to a value captured in a closure?

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime, borrowing

I wrote what I think is simple code:

```
#![feature(plugin)]
#![plugin(rocket_codegen)]

extern crate rocket;
extern crate statsd;

use rocket::{Data, Request};
use rocket::fairing::AdHoc;
use statsd::Client;

#[get("/")]
fn index() -> &'static str {
    "Hello, World"
}

fn main() {
    let mut client = Client::new("127.0.0.1:9125", "miniserver-rs").unwrap();

    rocket::ignite()
        .attach(AdHoc::on_request(|request, data|{
            client.incr("http.requests");
            println!("Request URI: {}", request.uri());
        }))
       .mount("/", routes![index])
       .launch();
   client.incr("server.bootstrap");
}
```

I try to send some metrics on each request, but I get the following compiler error:

```
   Compiling miniserver-rs v0.1.0 (main.rs)
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `client`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src\main.rs:19:33
   |
19 |       .attach(AdHoc::on_request(|request, _data|{
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ may outlive borrowed value `client`
20 |           client.incr("http.requests");
   |           ------ `client` is borrowed here help: to force the closure to take ownership of `client` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
19 |       .attach(AdHoc::on_request(move |request, _data|{
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0387]: cannot borrow data mutably in a captured outer variable in an `Fn` closure
  --> src\main.rs:20:11
   |
20 |           client.incr("http.requests");
   |           ^^^^^^
   |
help: consider changing this closure to take self by mutable reference
  --> src\main.rs:19:33
   |
19 |         .attach(AdHoc::on_request(|request, _data|{
   |  _________________________________^
20 | |           client.incr("http.requests");
21 | |           println!("Request URI: {}", request.uri());
22 | |       }))
   | |_______^
```

I understand that `client` is captured in a closure and owned by another function (`main`) that could live less than the closure. I cannot `move` it because `Client` doesn't implement `Copy`, so the reference could not be used afterwards.

I also understand that I cannot borrow mutable data in a closure (`Client` is mutable). After a lot of search, I can conclude I need to use `Arc`/`Rc` in combination with `Mutex`/`RwLock`/`RefCell`, but before going further, I want to be sure it is required.

Comment: _"I cannot move it because `Client` doesn't implement `Copy`"_ A better interpretation of that error message is that an attempt to use `client` was made after it was moved to the closure.

Comment: Nevertheless, the subsection of the book on [using `move` closures with threads](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch16-01-threads.html#using-move-closures-with-threads) shows that exact error. If you need to reuse that value outside that thread scope, [shared state](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch16-03-shared-state.html) might be needed, as you already predicted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the requirements. You want to call [`statsd::Client::incr(&mut client, metric)`](https://docs.rs/statsd/0.10.0/statsd/client/struct.Client.html#method.incr) from inside the closure, so you need mutable access to `client`. This is a variable you close over with `||`.

Now [`AdHoc::on_request<F>(f: F)`](https://api.rocket.rs/rocket/fairing/enum.AdHoc.html#method.on_request) requires `F: Fn(...) + Send + Sync + 'static`. `Fn` means you only have immutable access to your capture via `&self`. The `'static` bound means the capture cannot be a reference itself, so it requires `move ||`. Finally `Sync` means you can't use `Cell` or `RefCell` to get a mutable reference from `&self.client`, since Rocket will share it between threads.

Just like you suspected, the canonical solution to have shared mutable access through a `Send + Sync` value is to use `Arc<Mutex<_>>`. This also solves the problem of "losing access by moving". Your code would look like the following (untested):

```rust
fn main() {
    let client = Arc::new(Mutex::new(
        Client::new("127.0.0.1:9125", "miniserver-rs").unwrap()));

    // shallow-clone the Arc to move it into closure
    let rocket_client = client.clone();
    rocket::ignite()
        .attach(AdHoc::on_request(move |request, data|{
            rocket_client.lock()
                .unwrap()
                .incr("http.requests");

            println!("Request URI: {}", request.uri());
        }))
       .mount("/", routes![index])
       .launch();

   client.lock()
       .unwrap()
       .incr("server.bootstrap");
}
```

Comment: Yeepee!! This is almost (I wrote `Arc::clone(&client)` instead of `client.clone()`) the code I just finished to write! Thank you for the very precise answer, because I'm pretty sure I would have spent a huge amount of time to understand the reasons why I need Arc<Mutex<>> in this situation. Very insightful exercise :) Anyway, I will try to study this case further.

Comment: The relationship betwenn the `Fn` traits can be a bit confusing at first, but The Book has [a chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch13-01-closures.html) on that. For `Mutex`, `Arc` and cousins see [this chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch16-03-shared-state.html). Both long, but worth the read :)